# Unable to export CSS when exporting large HTML to PDF using mPDF

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii2, mpdf

I'm using mPDF to export a large table to a PDF. As I've read online, I need to break my HTML content into chunks and pass them to WriteHTML method one by one.
But looks like my bootstrap CSS is not getting exported when I do this. My table borders are not visible. No paddings...etc.

How can I achieve both these tasks?

This is my code:

```
    $content_chunks = str_split($content, 1000);

    $pdf = new Pdf();
    $mpdf = $pdf->api; // fetches mpdf api
    $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader(static::buildHeader());
    $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('Generated On: ' . date("r").'||{PAGENO}');

    foreach($content_chunks as $html)
    {
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    }

    return $mpdf->Output($file_name,'D');
```

[This is what the official docs say about breaking large HTML into chunks.](https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/known-issues.html#blank-pages-or-some-sections-missing) But I can't find any information with related to exporting bootstrap css.

Comment: try to split it by html tags, for example push in `WriteHTML` every 20 rows of table. Where you include css in your pdf?

Comment: Be aware that there are some [limitations in the css support](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/introduction.html).